# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{(x^2+\alpha^2)^2(e^x-1)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Hey I am trying to integrate
$$
I_n:=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{(x^2+\alpha^2)^2(e^x-1)^2}dx,\quad \alpha,n \geq 1.
$$
Thanks.
This integral is old. I am also looking for literature on these integrals as I have seen many for small values of n, and variations of this. Thanks. Maybe we can use residues. How can I make a contour with the $x^n$ piece involved with the possible quadrupole pole? Thanks

Comment: In order to converge, $\large n > 1$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Yes, thanks.  I made it clearer

Comment: @Lucian Your comment about this substitution and recognition of $\beta$ functions is also mentioned in many of your other solutions you post.  I am looking for a solution, this doesn't seem to help much here.  Thanks.

Comment: Special case, $n=2$. Is there any chance of using contour integration techniques to evaluate 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(\beta x^2+\alpha^2)(e^x-1)^2}dx,
$$
and differentiating the result w.r.t $\beta$? Setting $\beta=1$ would give $2I_2$, where $I_n$ is the integral you are interested in.

Comment: I just saw the condition $n>1$ for convergence how did you know that @FelixMarin?

Comment: @BennettGardiner When $\large x \sim 0$, the integrand behaves as $\large x^{n - 2}$ $\large\left(~\mbox{with}\  \alpha \not= 0~\right)$. Then, $\large n - 2 > -1$ and, finally, $\large n > 1$. Similarly, when $\large\alpha = 0$, $\large n > 5$.

Comment: I see, so more generally 
$$
I_n:=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{(x^2+\alpha^2)^p(e^x-1)^m}dx
$$
converges only for $n>m-1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{I_{n}\equiv\int_{0}^{\infty}
    {x^{n}\,\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} + \alpha^{2}}^{2}\pars{\expo{x} - 1}^{2}}\,,
     \qquad \alpha\,, n\ \geq\ 1}$.

> \begin{align}
> I_{n}&=-\,{1 \over 2\alpha}\,\partiald{}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {x^{n}\,\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} + \alpha^{2}}\pars{\expo{x} - 1}^{2}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over 2\alpha}\,\partiald{}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {1 \over 2\alpha\ic}\pars{{1 \over x - \alpha\ic} - {1 \over x + \alpha\ic}}{x^{n}\,\dd x \over \pars{\expo{x} - 1}^{2}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 2\alpha}\,\partiald{}{\alpha}\bracks{{1 \over \alpha}\,
> \Im\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {1 \over x + \alpha\ic}{x^{n}\,\dd x \over \pars{\expo{x} - 1}^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over 2\alpha}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}\ell\,\partiald{}{\alpha}\bracks{{1 \over \alpha^{2}}\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \pars{1 + {x \over \alpha\ic}}^{-1}x^{n}\expo{-\pars{\ell + 2}x}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over 2\alpha}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}
> {\ell \over \pars{\ell + 2}^{n + 1}}\,\partiald{}{\alpha}\bracks{%
> {1 \over \alpha^{2}}\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \bracks{1 + {x \over \pars{\ell + 2}\alpha\ic}}^{-1}x^{n}\expo{-x}\,\dd x}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}\color{#44f}{\large%
I_{n}}&=\color{#44f}{\large%
-\,{1 \over 2\alpha}\,\Gamma\pars{n + {3 \over 2}}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{\infty}
{\ell \over \pars{\ell + 2}^{3n/2 + 2}}\times}
\\[3mm]&\color{#44f}{\large\partiald{}{\alpha}\pars{%
{1 \over \alpha^{2}}\,\Re\braces{\pars{\alpha\ic}^{-n/2 - 1}\expo{\pars{\ell + 2}\alpha\ic}{\rm W}_{-n/2 - 1,n/2}\pars{\bracks{\ell + 2}\alpha\ic}}}}
\end{align}
with
$$
n \geq -\,{3 \over 2}\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
\pars{-n - {3 \over 2}} \not\in {\mathbb Z}
$$

> $\ds{{\rm W}_{k,m}\pars{z}}$ is the [Whittaker Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WhittakerFunction.html) ( see definition $\pars{5}$ in that link ). $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the
>   [Gamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.1}}$.