# Integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2axdx}{(x^{2}+a^{2})(e^{2\pi x}-1)} $

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

how could i evaluate the following integral ?=

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2axdx}{(x^{2}+a^{2})(e^{2\pi x}-1)} $$

for positive 'a' ??

i have tried the expansion of the integran $ exp(2\pi x) -1 $ into a power series of exponentials  $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-2n\pi x} $ but i would like to know if there is an easier method exists or if the integral is computed in tables.. ?

Comment: You could differentiate Binet's second log gamma formula. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html

Comment: @JoseGarcia http://residuetheorem.com/2014/01/15/integral-of-function-with-deceptive-triple-pole/

That is the problem you are looking for.  Just let $a^2\equiv 4\pi^2$, It is RonGordon's solution.  The user RonGordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{2ax\,\dd x \over \pars{x^{2} + a^{2}}\pars{\expo{2\pi x} - 1}}}
=2a\bracks{\half\,\ln\pars{a} - {1 \over 4a} - \half\,\Psi\pars{a}}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large a\bracks{\ln\pars{a} - \Psi\pars{a}} - \half}
\end{align}

> See $\ds{\bf\mbox{6.3.21}}$ in [A&S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm).

Comment: do you have a proof?  It is nice to know the integral has a name but do we know anything about its skeleton?  Thanks.

Comment: @Integrals  It's an Abel-Plana formula application to the Digamma Series. The series is found via Mittag-Leffler expansion. The identity is well known as it appears in Abramowitz et.al. and everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is an easier method using contours as Ron Gordon has showed us with this integral being treated identical, except he does the triple pole version.  I do not think these integrals are in a table, I am familiar with most tables and they are not in the ones I have.

You can write 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{2ax\, dx}{(x^{2}+a^{2})(e^{2\pi x}-1)}=2a \int_0^\infty \frac{x\, dx}{(x^{2}+a^{2})(e^{2\pi x}-1)}
$$
and define u=$2\pi x$ to obtain
$$
2a\int_0^\infty \frac{u\, du}{4\pi^2} \frac{1}{e^u-1}\frac{1}{\frac{u^2}{4\pi^2}+a^2}=\frac{a}{2\pi^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{u\, du}{(e^u-1)(a^2+\beta^2 u^2)},\quad
\beta^2\equiv (4\pi^2)^{-1}
$$
Now we can write
$$
I=\frac{a}{2\pi^2} \int_0^\infty \frac{u \, du}{(e^u-1)\big(\beta^2(u^2+\frac{a^2}{\beta^2})\big)}=\frac{a}{2\pi^2\beta^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{u\, du}{(e^u-1)(u^2+c^2)},\quad c\equiv \frac{a^2}{\beta^2}.
$$
Thus you want to solve
$$
I=\frac{c}{2\pi^2a}\int_0^\infty \frac{u \, du}{(e^u-1)(u^2+c^2)}.
$$
This is now the same problem as here http://residuetheorem.com/2014/01/15/integral-of-function-with-deceptive-triple-pole/, except yours is simpler.  That is the user $\bf{@Ron \ Gordon}$.  You can follow his solution till he evaluates the "ugly" triple pole.  Yours is clean because you have simple pole at $u=\pm i c$ and $u=i 2 n \pi, n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Of course we need to consider $c=2n\pi$ which will at most give us a double pole, which is still simpler than what Ron had done for us.  Thanks to Bennett Gardiner for making this clear

Also see this integral, I posted it, still no solution but they are very similar.  Yours is my case for $n=1$ and I have different denominator.  [Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{(x^2+\alpha^2)^2(e^x-1)^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747725/integral-int-0-infty-fracxnx2-alpha22ex-12dx)

Comment: Might the case $c = 2n\pi$ give some nuance then?

Comment: @BennettGardiner Of course.  However at most we have a double pole, ,which is still simpler than what Ron did for us

Comment: Indeed, just thought I'd mention it for completeness!

Comment: @BennettGardiner Okay, I see I will edit the post too.  Thanks again